# node.js + mysql connection pooling

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to figure out how to structure my application to use MySQL most efficent way. I'm using node-mysql module. Other threads here suggested to use connection pooling so i set up a little module mysql.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'guess'
});

exports.pool = pool;
```

Now whenever I want to query mysql I require this module and then query the databse

```
var mysql = require('../db/mysql').pool;

var test = function(req, res) {
     mysql.getConnection(function(err, conn){
         conn.query("select * from users", function(err, rows) {
              res.json(rows);
         })
     })
}
```

Is this good approach? I couldn't really find too much examples of using mysql connections besides very simple one where everything is done in main app.js script so I don't really know what the convention / best practices are.

Should I always use connection.end() after each query? What if I forget about it somewhere?

How to rewrite the exports part of my mysql module to return just a connection so I don't have to write getConnection() every time?

Comment: To those that find this and think "I have `connection.query` all over the place in my code" - it's probably time to refactor.  Build a database abstraction class that offers `select`, `insert`, `update`, etc - and only use `connection` (or `pool`) within that single db class...

Comment: @random_user_name do you have any links or code that implements your suggestion?

Comment: @random_user_name How would you manage transactions in this case?  If you release the connection after each query?

Comment: @JeffRyan you can have other classes that extend this db class in which you manage particular cases that require extraordinary transactions. But I think random_user_name's suggestion isn't necessarily against transactions... I generally use a similar pattern, in which I create a base model class that provides the basic methods, and the insertion method for example requires transactions, as it first inserts a record and then selects by last inserted ID to retrieve the result.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It's a good approach.

If you just want to get a connection add the following code to your module where the pool is in:

```
var getConnection = function(callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        callback(err, connection);
    });
};

module.exports = getConnection;
```

You still have to write getConnection every time. But you could save the connection in the module the first time you get it.

Don't forget to end the connection when you are done using it:

```
connection.release();
```

Comment: Just a heads up.  It's `connection.release();` now, for pools.

Comment: That's true. I changed it.

Comment: Also, if I may, I would suggest using a promise instead of callback, but that's just a preference... great solution nonetheless

Comment: @Spock can you link to an example of this? Express promises are kind of annoying to work with so far, I think I'm missing something. So far I can only use var deferred = q.defer() and then resolve or reject, but that seems like a lot of overhead for something so simple. If so, thanks :)

Comment: I'm, sorry about this late answer. Here is how I use promises to get a connection. I know it's a hazzle but consuming promises is so much nicer, I hate callbacks :) ..
`code`
var getConnection = function() {

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
        
        else {
            deferred.resolve connection);
        }
        
    });
    
    return deferred.promise;
};

Comment: Hi, just a question.How did you handle when pool got destroyed for some reason? I've considered this approach by seems i need to handle destroyed pool by create new pool?

Comment: @RomnickSusa that's different question and you should create new one

Comment: "But you could save the connection in the module the first time you get it." and "Don't forget to end the connection when you are done using it". These two statements seem to contradict each other. Is it a good practice to release the connection? Or is it to save it inside each module?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get how you call getConnection from external code. You need to path an cb-argument. What does that look like? Regarding the use of promisses: Is it possible to use async/ await?

Comment: You can also use `pool.query()` directly. This is a shortcut for the `pool.getConnection()` -> `connection.query()` -> `connection.release()` code flow.

Answer (score 45):

You should avoid using `pool.getConnection()` if you can. If you call `pool.getConnection()`, you **must** call `connection.release()` when you are done using the connection. Otherwise, your application will get stuck waiting forever for connections to be returned to the pool once you hit the connection limit.

For simple queries, you can use `pool.query()`. This shorthand will automatically call `connection.release()` for you—even in error conditions.

```js
function doSomething(cb) {
  pool.query('SELECT 2*2 "value"', (ex, rows) => {
    if (ex) {
      cb(ex);
    } else {
      cb(null, rows[0].value);
    }
  });
}
```

However, in some cases you must use `pool.getConnection()`. These cases include:

- Making multiple queries within a transaction.
- Sharing data objects such as temporary tables between subsequent queries.

If you must use `pool.getConnection()`, ensure you call `connection.release()` using a pattern similar to below:

```js
function doSomething(cb) {
  pool.getConnection((ex, connection) => {
    if (ex) {
      cb(ex);
    } else {
      // Ensure that any call to cb releases the connection
      // by wrapping it.
      cb = (cb => {
        return function () {
          connection.release();
          cb.apply(this, arguments);
        };
      })(cb);
      connection.beginTransaction(ex => {
        if (ex) {
          cb(ex);
        } else {
          connection.query('INSERT INTO table1 ("value") VALUES (\'my value\');', ex => {
            if (ex) {
              cb(ex);
            } else {
              connection.query('INSERT INTO table2 ("value") VALUES (\'my other value\')', ex => {
                if (ex) {
                  cb(ex);
                } else {
                  connection.commit(ex => {
                    cb(ex);
                  });
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I personally prefer to use `Promise`s and the `useAsync()` pattern. This pattern combined with `async`/`await` makes it a lot harder to accidentally forget to `release()` the connection because it turns your lexical scoping into an automatic call to `.release()`:

```js
async function usePooledConnectionAsync(actionAsync) {
  const connection = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.getConnection((ex, connection) => {
      if (ex) {
        reject(ex);
      } else {
        resolve(connection);
      }
    });
  });
  try {
    return await actionAsync(connection);
  } finally {
    connection.release();
  }
}

async function doSomethingElse() {
  // Usage example:
  const result = await usePooledConnectionAsync(async connection => {
    const rows = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query('SELECT 2*4 "value"', (ex, rows) => {
        if (ex) {
          reject(ex);
        } else {
          resolve(rows);
        }
      });
    });
    return rows[0].value;
  });
  console.log(`result=${result}`);
}
```

Comment: +1 - just a note - awaiting every query may not make sense in instances where you are running multiple queries that could in practice be run simultaneously instead of sequentially.

Comment: @cale_b Unless you are doing something weirdly magical, running these queries in parallel is impossible. If you are running multiple queries in a transaction with data dependencies, you cannot run the second query until you are certain the first one has completed. If your queries are sharing a transaction, as demonstrated, they are also sharing a connection. Each connection supports only one query at a time (there is no such thing as [MARS](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-2017) in MySQL).

Comment: If you in fact are performing multiple independent operations in the database, nothing is stopping you from calling `usePooledConnectionAsync()` multiple times prior to completion of the first one. Note that, with pooling, you will want to make sure that you avoid `await`ing events other than query completion within the function you pass as `actionAsync`—otherwise, you might end up creating a deadlock (e.g., get the last connection from a pool, then call another function which tries to load data using the pool which will wait forever to try to get its own connection from the pool when empty).

Comment: Thanks for engaging.  This may be an area my understanding is weak - but, previously (before switching to pools, using your answer primarily, BTW) I had multiple selects running in "parallel" (and then I merge the results in my js logic after they come back).  I don't think that's magical, but it seemed like a good strategy to NOT `await` one before asking for the next.  I haven't done any analysis now, but the way I've authored things (returning new Promises), I think it's _still_ running in parallel...

Comment: @cale_b Right, I’m not saying that pattern is bad. If you need to load multiple pieces of data and it can be assumed that they are either independent or sufficiently unchanging, launching a bunch of independent loads and then only `await`ing them when you actually need them to compose the results together is a way to do it (though I’m scared that would result in false positive unhandled promise rejection events which might crash node.js in the future with `--unhandled-rejections=strict`).

Comment: Of course, each of those loads would be on a different connection from the pool. If you cannot tell, in my answer, I describe a situation where multiple queries need to share the same connection. For example, if you create a temporary table in one statement, insert rows into it in another statement, and then use that temporary table in a third statement, you will need to use a single connection multiple times instead of being able to use `pool.query()`. Also, those particular queries will have to be run sequentially. Do you see?

Answer (score 16):

You will find this wrapper usefull :)

```
var pool = mysql.createPool(config.db);

exports.connection = {
    query: function () {
        var queryArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
            events = [],
            eventNameIndex = {};

        pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
            if (err) {
                if (eventNameIndex.error) {
                    eventNameIndex.error();
                }
            }
            if (conn) { 
                var q = conn.query.apply(conn, queryArgs);
                q.on('end', function () {
                    conn.release();
                });

                events.forEach(function (args) {
                    q.on.apply(q, args);
                });
            }
        });

        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                events.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
                eventNameIndex[eventName] = callback;
                return this;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Require it, use it like this:

```
db.connection.query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = ? ", row_id)
          .on('result', function (row) {
            setData(row);
          })
          .on('error', function (err) {
            callback({error: true, err: err});
          });
```

Answer (score 14):

I am using this base class connection with mysql:

"base.js"

```
var mysql   = require("mysql");

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: Config.appSettings().database.host,
    user: Config.appSettings().database.username,
    password: Config.appSettings().database.password,
    database: Config.appSettings().database.database
});


var DB = (function () {

    function _query(query, params, callback) {
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                connection.release();
                callback(null, err);
                throw err;
            }

            connection.query(query, params, function (err, rows) {
                connection.release();
                if (!err) {
                    callback(rows);
                }
                else {
                    callback(null, err);
                }

            });

            connection.on('error', function (err) {
                connection.release();
                callback(null, err);
                throw err;
            });
        });
    };

    return {
        query: _query
    };
})();

module.exports = DB;
```

Just use it like that:

```
var DB = require('../dal/base.js');

DB.query("select * from tasks", null, function (data, error) {
   callback(data, error);
});
```

Comment: What if the query's `err` is true? shouldn't it still call `callback` with `null` parameter to indicate there is some error in the query?

Comment: Yes, you write, need to bubble up callback with the query error

Comment: Nice one. But you should add an `else` condition like this: `if (!err) {
                    callback(rows, err);
                } else { callback(null, err); }` else your application might hang. Because `connection.on('error', callback2)` won't take care of all "errors". Thanks!

Comment: exactly, i added this fix

Comment: nodejs newbe here:  Why do you have function (data, error) and callback(data, error); when most of all the nodejs code I've seen is error as the first param and the data/callback as the second param?  ex: callback(error, results)

Answer (score 2):

When you are done with a connection, just call `connection.release()` and the connection will return to the pool, ready to be used again by someone else.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool(...);

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // Use the connection
  connection.query('SELECT something FROM sometable', function (error, results, fields) {
    // And done with the connection.
    connection.release();

    // Handle error after the release.
    if (error) throw error;

    // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
  });
});
```

If you would like to close the connection and remove it from the pool, use `connection.destroy()` instead. The pool will create a new connection the next time one is needed.

**Source**: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard mysql.createPool(), connections are lazily created by the pool. If you configure the pool to allow up to 100 connections, but only ever use 5 simultaneously, only 5 connections will be made. However if you configure it for 500 connections and use all 500 they will remain open for the durations of the process, even if they are idle!

This means if your MySQL Server max_connections is 510 your system will only have 10 mySQL connections available until your MySQL Server closes them (depends on what you have set your wait_timeout to) or your application closes! The only way to free them up is to manually close the connections via the pool instance or close the pool.

mysql-connection-pool-manager module was created to fix this issue and automatically scale the number of connections dependant on the load. Inactive connections are closed and idle connection pools are eventually closed if there has not been any activity.

```
    // Load modules
const PoolManager = require('mysql-connection-pool-manager');

// Options
const options = {
  ...example settings
}

// Initialising the instance
const mySQL = PoolManager(options);

// Accessing mySQL directly
var connection = mySQL.raw.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

// Initialising connection
connection.connect();

// Performing query
connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

// Ending connection
connection.end();
```

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-connection-pool-manager

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format as I used

```
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const { HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME, PORT } = process.env;
    console.log();
    const conn = mysql.createPool({
        host: HOST,
        user: USERNAME,
        password: PASSWORD,
        database: DBNAME
    }, { debug: true });
    
    conn.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log('Db is connected - The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
    });
    
    
    module.exports = conn;
```

Answer (score -7):

i always use connection.relase(); after pool.getconnetion like

```
pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
      connection.release();
        if (!err)
        {
            console.log('*** Mysql Connection established with ', config.database, ' and connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
            //CHECKING USERNAME EXISTENCE
            email = receivedValues.email
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email],
                function (err, rows) {
                    if (!err)
                    {
                        if (rows.length == 1)
                        {
                            if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, rows[0].password))
                            {
                                var alldata = rows;
                                var userid = rows[0].id;
                                var tokendata = (receivedValues, userid);
                                var token = jwt.sign(receivedValues, config.secret, {
                                    expiresIn: 1440 * 60 * 30 // expires in 1440 minutes
                                });
                                console.log("*** Authorised User");
                                res.json({
                                    "code": 200,
                                    "status": "Success",
                                    "token": token,
                                    "userData": alldata,
                                    "message": "Authorised User!"
                                });
                                logger.info('url=', URL.url, 'Responce=', 'User Signin, username', req.body.email, 'User Id=', rows[0].id);
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                console.log("*** Redirecting: Unauthorised User");
                                res.json({"code": 200, "status": "Fail", "message": "Unauthorised User!"});
                                logger.error('*** Redirecting: Unauthorised User');
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.error("*** Redirecting: No User found with provided name");
                            res.json({
                                "code": 200,
                                "status": "Error",
                                "message": "No User found with provided name"
                            });
                            logger.error('url=', URL.url, 'No User found with provided name');
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("*** Redirecting: Error for selecting user");
                        res.json({"code": 200, "status": "Error", "message": "Error for selecting user"});
                        logger.error('url=', URL.url, 'Error for selecting user', req.body.email);
                        return;
                    }
                });
            connection.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log('*** Redirecting: Error Creating User...');
                res.json({"code": 200, "status": "Error", "message": "Error Checking Username Duplicate"});
                return;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Errors.Connection_Error(res);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't think you should be releasing the connection *before* you use it to query

Comment: Yes, this is bad news .... its a side effect of the async nature of things that you are getting away with this release. If you introduce some latency you won't see that query. The pattern is ...

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // Use the connection 
  connection.query('SELECT something FROM sometable', function (error, results, fields) {
    // And done with the connection. 
    connection.release();
    // Handle error after the release. 
    if (error) throw error;

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections