# How to provide a mysql database connection in single file in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-modules

I need to provide the mysql connection for modules. I have a code like this.

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app);

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database    : 'chat'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
});

app.get('/save', function(req,res){
    var post  = {from:'me', to:'you', msg:'hi'};
    var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO messages SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

But how we provide one time mysql connection for all the modules.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You could create a db wrapper then require it. node's require returns the same instance of a module every time, so you can perform your connection and return a handler. From the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching):

> every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

You could create `db.js`:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'chat'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Then in your `app.js`, you would simply require it.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var db = require('./db');

app.get('/save',function(req,res){
    var post  = {from:'me', to:'you', msg:'hi'};
    db.query('INSERT INTO messages SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

This approach allows you to abstract any connection details, wrap anything else you want to expose and require `db` throughout your application while maintaining one connection to your db thanks to how node require works :)

Comment: In this way how we create io=require('socket.io'); for any route access.

Comment: @Sean3z are you sure that `connection.connect()` will not create a connection each time the file is `require`d?

Comment: I realize I'm a bit late to the party, but what is the conventional place to put a db.js file in an express app?

Comment: Tell me please, and the absence of closing the connection will not consume a lot of memory?

Comment: On Windows, there is a corner case to be aware of with this convention: (1) node.js caches exports based on the string passed to require(), and this string cache is case sensitive; (2) since Windows paths are case insensitive, this would actually create 2 instances of your db connection.  As long as your require statements are cased the same across all files, this will not be an issue.

Comment: can you tell me where to put this db.js file, i am put it in root folder it give me error Error: Cannot find module './db'

Comment: Error: connection.query is not a function

Comment: I have a question about using Transactions in this situation. Will it cause some problems if to reuse a connection across multiple requests?

Comment: Before going to insert the record, how can I make sure that the connection has been made successfully?

Comment: Connection pooling is more optimal than using a single connection. The same pattern can be used for a connection pool. Refer [this](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) for implementation.

Comment: I have multiple files that needed to be queried, validators to be specific, If i require that `db.js` to those file, will it only be a single connection?

Answer (score 20):

I took a similar approach as Sean3z but instead I have the connection closed everytime i make a query.

His way works if it's only executed on the entry point of your app, but let's say you have controllers that you want to do a `var db = require('./db')`. You can't because otherwise everytime you access that controller you will be creating a new connection.

To avoid that, i think it's safer, in my opinion, to open and close the connection everytime.

here is a snippet of my code.

**mysq_query.js**

```
// Dependencies
var mysql   = require('mysql'),
    config  = require("../config");

/*
 * @sqlConnection
 * Creates the connection, makes the query and close it to avoid concurrency conflicts.
 */
var sqlConnection = function sqlConnection(sql, values, next) {

    // It means that the values hasnt been passed
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        next = values;
        values = null;
    }

    var connection = mysql.createConnection(config.db);
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err !== null) {
            console.log("[MYSQL] Error connecting to mysql:" + err+'\n');
        }
    });

    connection.query(sql, values, function(err) {

        connection.end(); // close the connection

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        // Execute the callback
        next.apply(this, arguments);
    });
}

module.exports = sqlConnection;
```

Than you can use it anywhere just doing like

```
var mysql_query = require('path/to/your/mysql_query');
mysql_query('SELECT * from your_table where ?', {id: '1'}, function(err, rows)   {
    console.log(rows);
});
```

**UPDATED:**
config.json looks like

```
{
        "db": {
        "user"     : "USERNAME",
        "password" : "PASSWORD",
        "database" : "DATABASE_NAME",
        "socketPath": "/tmp/mysql.sock"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @harshvardhan I have updated it in the information with the config info.

Comment: I am getting the following error in console:

"db":{
     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Ok, So i have set the **config.json** object in **mysql_query.js** file itself and then there is no syntax problem. But again, I am getting the following error in console:  **[MYSQL] Error connecting to mysql:Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

I have password in my db, and when I try to log on my MySQL db through the same credentials on command line, I am through it.

Comment: @harshvardhan I'm afraid that now its just a matter of configuration. Try having a look at the documentation of the package. https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should use a connection pool instead of share a single connection. A connection pool would provide a much better performance, as you can check [here](http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2016/09/05/nodejs-connection-pooling.html).

As stated in the library [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#executing-queries-in-parallel), it occurs because the MySQL protocol is sequential (this means that you need multiple connections to execute queries in parallel).

[Connection Pool Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections)

Answer (score 1):

From the node.js documentation, "To have a module execute code multiple times, export a function, and call that function", you could use node.js module.export and have a single file to manage the db connections.You can find more at [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html). Let's say db.js file be like:

```
    const mysql = require('mysql');

    var connection;

    module.exports = {

    dbConnection: function () {

        connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            user: "Your_user",
            password: "Your_password",
            database: 'Your_bd'
        });
        connection.connect();
        return connection;
    }

    };
```

Then, the file where you are going to use the connection could be like useDb.js:

```
const dbConnection = require('./db');

var connection;

function callDb() {

    try {

        connection = dbConnectionManager.dbConnection();

        connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (!error) {

                let response = "The solution is: " + results[0].solution;
                console.log(response);

            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        connection.end();


    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'yourip',
    port    : 'yourport',
    user     : 'dbusername',
    password : 'dbpwd',
    database : 'database schema name',
    dateStrings: true,
    multipleStatements: true
});


// TODO - if any pool issues need to try this link for connection management
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496540/node-js-mysql-connection-pooling

module.exports = function(qry, qrytype, msg, callback) {

if(qrytype != 'S') {
    console.log(qry);
}

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) {
        if(connection)
            connection.release();
        throw err;
    } 

    // Use the connection
    connection.query(qry, function (err, results, fields) {
        connection.release();

        if(err) {
            callback('E#connection.query-Error occurred.#'+ err.sqlMessage);    
            return;         
        }

        if(qrytype==='S') {
            //for Select statement
            // setTimeout(function() {
                callback(results);      
            // }, 500);
        } else if(qrytype==='N'){
            let resarr = results[results.length-1];
            let newid= '';
            if(resarr.length)               
                newid = resarr[0]['@eid'];
            callback(msg + newid);
        } else if(qrytype==='U'){
            //let ret = 'I#' + entity + ' updated#Updated rows count: ' + results[1].changedRows;
            callback(msg);                      
        } else if(qrytype==='D'){
            //let resarr = results[1].affectedRows;
            callback(msg);
        }
    });

    connection.on('error', function (err) {
        connection.release();
        callback('E#connection.on-Error occurred.#'+ err.sqlMessage);   
        return;         
    });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var express = require('express');

var mysql     =    require('mysql');

var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
console.log(app);
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "admin123",
  database: "sitepoint"
});

con.connect(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log('Error connecting to Db');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connection established');
});



module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a global variable and then access that variable in other files.

> here is my code, I have created a separate file for MySQL database connection called db.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "xxxxx",
    database: "test"
});

conn.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected to the MySql DB');
});

module.exports = conn;
```

> Then in the app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// MySql Db connection and set in globally
global.db = require('../config/db');
```

> Now you can use it in any other file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    try {
        var param = req.body;
        var sql = `select * from user`;

        // db is global variable
        db.query(sql, (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw new SyntaxError(err);
            res.status(200).json({ 'auth': true, 'data': data });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ 'auth': false, 'data': err.message });
    }
});
```