# Node.Js export variable issue

Tags: mysql, node.js

//Connection.js (module) that is require.

```
var mysql = require ('mysql');

var con ;
con = mysql.createConnection ({
       host : 'localhost',
       user : 'root' ,
       password : 'root',
       database : 'mydb'
});


exports.con = con;

module.exports  = con.connect ( function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected!");
    });
```

//controller.js

var connection = require ('./connection');
var mysql = require ('mysql');

```
console.log(connection.con);
var sql = "Select * from user;";
connection.con.query(sql , function (err,result) {
    if(err) throw  err;
    console.log(result);
});
```

when I run the connection.js with the same query it works but when using the module in `controller.js` it gives me the error.
//error code

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'con' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt is almost right. Except,

```
module.exports  = con.connect ( function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

By doing that, you are replacing, `exports` with `con.connect()` call response, which overwrites previously assigned `con` property. If you remove that, you should be okay!

```
var mysql = require ('mysql');

var con ;
con = mysql.createConnection ({
  host : 'localhost',
  user : 'root' ,
  password : 'root',
  database : 'mydb'
});


exports.con = con;

con.connect ( function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

For reference check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30545872/7621143)(shared by @Aky_0788).

Answer (score 0):

```
//Connection.js (module) that is require.

var mysql = require ('mysql');

var con ;
con = mysql.createConnection ({
     host : 'localhost',
     user : 'root' ,
     password : 'root',
     database : 'mydb'
});

con.connect ( function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected!");
});

exports.con = con;
```

controller.js

```
var connection = require ('./connection');
var mysql = require ('mysql');
console.log(connection.con);
var sql = "Select * from user;";
connection.con.query(sql , function (err,result) {
    if(err) throw  err;
    console.log(result);
});
```