# Should a node.js server have a single connection to a mysql instance?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Say I have app.js as the main app on the server, and it imports(requires) 4 other scripts that route login, join, write article, delete article requests. I currently have connection instances through
`var connection = mysql.createConnection(mysqlConfig)` in EACH of the login.js, join.js, write.js, delete.js.
I have a feeling that this is bad practice. What should I do? Should I create a mysqlconnection.js that exports a connection instance, and require that in each of the scripts that require a connection?

Comment: Please try connection pooling. This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496540/node-js-mysql-connection-pooling

Answer (score 1):

Deciding the number of connections depends on your application. If you have a sporadically used application with very few calls to mysql, then a single connection might work. However, looking at your use case, it seems that multiple users will be trying to login, write, etc. In such a case I recommend using Connection Pooling.  https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool

Comment: `mysql` has [built-in connection pooling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections).