# confusion about how connection.end() works in node.js mySQL module

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, angular

```
const mysql = require('mysql'); 
let connection = mysql.createConnection(...);
        connection.connect((err)=>{
           ...
           connection.query((err)=>{
           ...
           connection.end();});
        });
```

After I close the connection by using

> connection.end()

, if I want to query the database again using the same credentials, do I need to make a new connection by calling

> mysql.createConnection(...)

Or can I reuse the same connection by simply calling

> connection.connect(...)

A little background: I'm deploying an angular/node.js app to a shared hosting website, and the web host has a maximum limit of 25 concurrent connections to mySQL database, therefore I need to make sure I close a connection properly after a user does his query. I am not sure if I could reuse the connection created by mysql.createConnection(...) after I close that connection, or do I need to create a brand new connection.

Comment: You'll want a pool. Configure it to not use more than 25 connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one global connection for getting data from db .

If You working on single file than you can write as

**app.js one file only**

```
 var mysql      = require('mysql');
 var connection = mysql.createConnection(...);

    connection.query('SELECT 1', function (error, results, fields) {
     if (error) throw error;
   // connected!
  });
```

if you want to use same connection in  multiple file than you can write as
**app.js**

```
 app.use(  
    connection(mysql, {
         host: xxxxx, 
         user: 'root',
         password : xxxx, 
         port : 3306, 
         database:dbname

     },'pool'),  
   );

  var oem = require('./routes/type');
  app.get('/api/oemtype',oem.type);
```

For the second file 
**type.js**

```
   exports.type = function(req, res){

     req.getConnection(function(err,connection){

      var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM type',function(err,rows)
      {
          if(err)
          res.json({
            status:0
        });

              res.send(rows);
         res.render('customers',{page_title:"Customers - Node.js",data:rows});


       });

  });

   };
```

No need to use of connection.end().

Comment: The web host I am deploying my app to has a maximum limit of 25 concurrent connections to mySQL database. Will not calling connection.end( ) leave the connection hanging, therefore causing problems to the maximum limit?

Comment: If you end the connection every time then mysql create every time new connection It will decrease the performance of the app and mysql. It's better to use pool connection.

Comment: Does the pool create a single pool for all users? For instance, if I set the connectionLimit to 25 (as in var pool=mysql.createPool({connectionLimit:10, host:...}); will this create a connection pool of 25 for each user or will this create a connection pool of 25 for all users?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, pool will be create for all 25 user not for each user.. instead of end mehod you can use connection.release() after query work is done. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496540/node-js-mysql-connection-pooling

Comment: Thanks! This is new knowledge to me and I will do more research myself :)