# nodejs to mysql connection denied with root

Tags: mysql, node.js, ubuntu, xampp

I have a nodejs app which get some data from mysql database in same server. I am using xampp in ubuntu 16.04. The database connection from **php and phpmyadmin is fine** and working nicely. But my nodejs page can not connect to mysql database and giving me

`code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR', errno: 1045, sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'x.x.x.x' (using password: YES)", sqlState: '28000', fatal: true`

I have given all grants to root user in mysql database.

My nodejs connection is as follows:

```html
const mysql = require('mysql');
const moment = require('moment');
var mycon = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: 'x.x.x.x',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'myPass',
    database: 'myDatabase',
    multipleStatements: true 
});
```

I am using node version 14.13.0 . Any suggestion regarding this painful situation?

Comment: Could you please try with password='' with empty

Comment: May be, this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477625/nodejs-mysql-er-eccess-denied-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: Hello, I have tried all the variations mentioned in the link above... but i m getting same error again and again.... i changed the user to something else but getting error for user root only. very frustrated situation

Comment: insted of x.x.x.x, can you please try localhost

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496540/node-js-mysql-connection-pooling/18496936

Comment: I checked with 'localhost' and also 127.0.0.1 instead of x.x.x.x but still getting same error.... very strangely it always points to root@x.x.x.x even i changed the username to another user with root privileges.